# where django store request['user'] in what file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

As mentioned in the documentation, authenticated user's object is stored within user variable in templates. i need where django stored user variable in apps file thanks:

```
user = request.user
request['user'] = user #where is?
```

thanks for help

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? If you ask where the class definition of the user class is, it is located in `admin.contrib.auth.models`

Comment: in what core apps django create the variable request['user'] I'm browsing directories but i dont know in what app create that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

The official doc mentioned it:

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#installation):

> AuthenticationMiddleware associates users with requests using
>   sessions.

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware):

> class AuthenticationMiddleware
>
> Adds the user attribute, representing
>   the currently-logged-in user, to every incoming HttpRequest object.
>   See Authentication in Web requests.

source code(django.contrib.auth.middleware.py):

```
class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'."

        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). Otherwise `user` is not available in the templates.